# Eiffel test program error

Tags: numbers, eiffel

im trying to learn Eiffel language,and im just trying to make a very basic program that would display a given number.However,I keep getting an error without any explanation:

```
note
description : " application root class"
date        : "$Date$"
revision    : "$Revision$"

class
    APPLICATION


create
    make
feature  -- Initialization
        make

        do

            testvar: INTEGER  --error occur here"syntax error" 
            set_testvar (new_testvar : INTEGER)
            testvar:= new_testvar
            Io.put_integer (testvar)
            print ("Hello Eiffel World!%N")
        end

end
```

It might be a very dumb mistake but im learning.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare local variable in the local section of the `make' routine like this:

```
make
    local
        testvar:INTEGER
    do
        Io.put_integer(testvar)
    end
```